# Wikipedia Definition: $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Wikipedia defines (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets#Sigma_algebras_and_measure_spaces)):

> If an algebra over a set is closed under countable intersections and countable unions, it is called a sigma algebra...

Is this really equivalent to the usual definition of a $\sigma$-algebra??

Comment: That depends on your "usual definition".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the definition already requires "an algebra", which means closure under complements, and that the space itself is an element of the algebra.

In effect, requiring either one of countable intersection or countable unions suffices because of the above (and DeMorgan laws).

Answer (score 0):

That's not what I see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_algebra
This is more like what I would expect.

Moreover, if you read the intro material at your link, you will see they add the usual properties you expect. From your link:

"...closed under the intersection and union of pairs of sets and under complements of individual sets..."

They add count ability to the definition of an algebra to obtain a sigma algebra, which is correct.